# Error on Grails startup: Cannot invoke method contains() on null object

Tags: grails

I have downloaded and installed Grails 2.3.6 and tried to create a new app (as I'm trying to learn using Grails). Unfortunately I'm getting this error whenever Grails is loading, for example:

```
C:\Users\me>grails help --stacktrace

| Loading Grails 2.3.6
| Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Cannot invoke method contain
s() on null object (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see en
tire trace.)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method contains() on null object
        at settings.run(settings.groovy:24)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadSettingsFile(BuildSettings.groovy:1302)

        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1063)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:1053)
| Error There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Cannot invoke method contain
s() on null object
```

What could cause this problem?

Some information on my system:

```
C:\Users\me>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

C:\Users\me>echo %GRAILS_HOME%
C:\grails-2.3.6
```

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro (x64)

Any hints are highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The issue stems from your BuildConfig file. Can you post your BuildConfig.groovy?

Comment: Is there a `settings.groovy` file in your home directory or in the `.grails` directory immediately below your home directory?  If yes, look in that file for anything suspicious.

Comment: um... as Grails isn't loading properly, I don't have a grails app yet. So the only BuildConfig.groovy I can give you is the original C:\grails-2.3.6\src\grails\grails-app\conf\BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rrTS9icj